# Modelling ownership in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Things` and I want to add ownership relations to a table `Users`. I need to be able to quickly query the owners of a thing and the things a user owns. If I know that there will be at most 50 owners, and the pdf for the number of owners will probably look like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BLogNormalDistribution[1%2C+1]%7D), should I rather

- add 50 columns to the `Things` table, like `CoOwner1Id`, `CoOwner2Id`, …, `CoOwner50Id`, or
- should I model this with a `Ownerships` table which has `UserId` and `ThingId` columns, or
- would it better to create a table for each thing, for example `Thing8321Owners` with a row for each owner, or
- perhaps a combination of these?

Comment: Option 2. Always. Every time you have something else in mind, slap yourself. It's better to suffer from your own hand than someone else's.

Comment: strictly follow N.B.'s suggestion...

Comment: Incidentally, there are three instances above where you had something else in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second choice is the correct one; you should create an intermediate table between the table Things and the table Owners (that contains the details of each owner).
This table should have the thing_id and the owner_id as the primary key.
So finally, you well have 3 tables:

- Things (the things details and data)
- Owner (the owners details and data)
- Ownerships (the assignment of each thing_id to an owner_id)

Because in a relational DB you should not have any redundant data.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely go with option 2 because what you are trying to model is a [many to many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)). (Many owners can relate to a thing. Many things can relate to an owner.) This is commonly accomplished using what I call a [bridging table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). (Which exactly what option 2 is.) It is a standard technique in a normalized database.

The other two options are going to give you nightmares trying to query or maintain.

With option 1 you'll need to join the `User` table to the `Thing` table on **50** columns to get all of your results. And what happens when you have a really popular thing that 51 people want to own?

Option 3 is even worse. The only way to easily query the data is to use dynamic  sql or write a new query each time because you don't know which `Thing*Owners` table to join on until you know the ID value of the thing you're looking for. Or you're going to need to join the `User` table to every single `Thing*Owners` table. Adding a new thing means creating a whole new table. But at least a thing doesn't have a limit on the number of owners it could possibly have.

Now isn't this:

```
SELECT Users.Name, Things.Name
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Ownership ON Users.UserId=Ownership.UserId
INNER JOIN Things ON Things.ThingId=Ownership.ThingId
```

much easier than any of those other scenarios?